# Why does 'apt-get install nodejs -y' not install npm?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, apt-get, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following `bitbucket.pipelines.yml`:

```
image: python:3.5.1

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install nodejs -y
            - npm install
            - npm run build
            - python get-pip.py
            - pip install boto3==1.3.0
            - python s3_upload.py io-master.fromthiscomesthat.co.uk dist io-master
```

Having installed node, the build then fails trying to run `npm`:

```
+ npm install
bash: npm: command not found
```

I imagine this is because `npm` is not in the path. Or something. My Ubuntu/UNIX skills are not the best.

How can I add the install to the path?

## Update

Ok, after a lot of fiddling my YAML now looks like this:

```
image: python:3.5.1

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install lsb-release -y
            - curl --silent https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | apt-key add -
            - VERSION=node_5.x
            - DISTRO="$(lsb-release -s -c)" # <--- error here
            - echo "deb https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
            - echo "deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/$VERSION $DISTRO main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get install nodejs -y
            - npm install
            - npm run build
            - python get-pip.py
            - pip install boto3==1.3.0
            - python s3_upload.py io-master.fromthiscomesthat.co.uk dist io-master
```

Now I have a smaller problem. `lsb-release` is not being found, even though the installer installs it correctly. Is this a path issue?; how can I execute this when I don't know where it's being installed to? It's difficult to debug because it's running in a docker instance on Bitbucket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu contains a version of Node.js in its default repositories that can be used but it only includes the node binary. If you want to install `npm` you can do it by typing:

`apt-get install npm`

However, I recommend you to add the PPA (personal package archive) maintained by NodeSource. This will probably have more up-to-date versions of Node.js than the official Ubuntu repositories.

You need to install the PPA to get access to its contents, and then you can install the `nodejs` package in the same way that you did above.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Using this option, the nodejs package contains the nodejs binary as well as npm, so you don't need to install npm separately.

Comment: That's great, thanks; however I have another problem which I have described above. Any ideas?